# On the canonical neighborhoods

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Suppose $M$ is a 3-dimensional manifold, John W. Morgan and Frederick Tsz-Ho Fong in their "Ricci Flow
and Geometrization
of 3-Manifolds" book as a definition of canonical neighborhoods have written:

> We fix an $\epsilon >0$, there are essentially $3$ types of $\epsilon$-canonical neighborhoods:
>
> (1) ($\epsilon$-neck) - a neighborhood $N_{\epsilon}\subset M$ diffeomorphic to $S^2\times (-\epsilon ^{-1},\epsilon ^{-1})$ under diffeomorphism $\varphi:S^2\times (-\epsilon ^{-1},\epsilon ^{-1})\to N_\epsilon$, such that the rescaled pull-back metric $R(x,t)\varphi ^*g(t)$ on $S^2\times (-\epsilon ^{-1},\epsilon ^{-1})$ is within $\epsilon$ in $C^{[\epsilon^{-1}]}$-topology to the product of the round metric on $S^2$ with $R=1$ with the usual metric on $(-\epsilon ^{-1},\epsilon ^{-1})$.
>
> (2) ($\epsilon$-cap) - topologically $B^3$ or a punctured real projective $3$-space $\mathbb{R}P^3_0$ and whose end is a $\epsilon$-neck.
>
> (3) connected component of positive sectional curvature.
>
> A point $x\in M$ is said to **have an $\epsilon$-canonical neighborhood** if it lies in the
> central two-sphere of an $\epsilon$-neck, lies in an $\epsilon$-cap in the complement of the $\epsilon$-neck
> forming the end of the cap, or lies in a component of positive sectional curvature.

**Question 1:** What is the meaning of "*within $\epsilon$ in $C^{[\epsilon^{-1}]}$-topology*"?

**Question 2:** Why do we consider **rescaled** pull-back metric $R(x,t)\varphi ^*g(t)$? What is necessity of this action? In other words if we have just considered pull-back metric $\varphi ^*g(t)$, what would be wrong then?

**Question 3:** Is the boundary of the punctured real projective $3$-space ,$\mathbb{R}P^3_0$, $S^2$?

**Question 4:** I can visualize $\epsilon$-neck and $\epsilon$-cap. These types of canonical neighborhoods have shapes like following figures. Now, what is visualization of type (3) of the definition of the canonical neighborhoods? Essentially, what is "*a component of positive sectional curvature*" ?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question one:

They want to consider the semi-norms induced topology as a Fréchet Space, so basically is the topology of "almost" infinite differentiable functions (almost as epsilon is really small, so $\epsilon^{-1}$ is a really big number.

Question 2:

Is mostly used to be able to recuperate the action of the metric you crecovered in the original manifold, i mean, you have a metric which is defined on a component that is about to turn to a singularity and you want to study it in a different space, that is, the original manifold under the ricci flow action, thus, rescalling.

answer to question 4:

"a component of positive sectional curvature" is basically something that locally has positive sectional curvature, which turns out to be a sphere. (you can check DoCarmo´s book in riemannian geometry for details). Another apprach to visualizing this may be the spherical space forms (Wol´s book spaces of constant curvature has a quite etailed exposition in this matter) so it is a space where the geometry tells you to move according to a constant positive sectional curvature (in each point you "feel" like moving as you do in a sphere).

You also want to note that despite ricci flow uses, there is a normalized ricci flow which is volume-preserving and with it, you can study the changes in the topology and geometry of your manifold M without changing it "too much" (thus, perelman´s idea of recovering the original manifold uses the normalized ricci flow).